# Not working in latest jquery versions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why this code is not working in latest versions of jQuery?

```js
    $('.head').click(function(){
         if($(this).next('#list').hasClass('block')){
            $(this).next('#list').removeClass('block');
         }
        else{
          $(this).parent().find('#list').removeClass('block');
           $(this).next().addClass('block');
        }
    });
```

```css
#list{
  display:none;
}

.head{
  border: 1px solid #e6dfdf;
  background: #efdbdb;
  padding:5px;
  margin:5px 0;
}
#menu{
  display:inline-block;
}
.block{
  display:block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <div class="head" >head1</div>
  <ul id="list">
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="head" >head2</div>
    <ul id="list">
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item2</li>
      <li>item3</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="head" >head3</div>
      <ul id="list">
        <li>
            <div class="head" >head3</div>
            <ul id="list">
              <li>item1</li>
              <li>item2</li>
              <li>item3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>item2</li>
        <li>item3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Here is the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/silpajacob449/y39wk6mn/

Comment: Which jQuery version ?

Comment: Appears to be working with 3.2.1 https://jsfiddle.net/y39wk6mn/1/

Comment: when we click on 3rd heading its second heading's content remains opened

Comment: Issue showing in 1.9.1,3.2.1.and also in some other versions.In 1.5.1 it is fine@JaydeepMor

Comment: code is not working or functionality is not working?

Comment: functionality is not working @sarancheln

Comment: after u clicked third's child head rite?

Comment: In which version is supporting this?can u tell that jquery old version?

Comment: its working in 1.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

id is unique identify, try to change #list to .list